# Spring BeanDefinition getDestroyMethodName always returns null

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to analyze bean configuration and I'd like to log some messages in specific cases. I think `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is the right place for this. However, when I loop through `beanDefinitions` and call `getDestroyMethodName` or `getInitMethodName` it always returns null.

I specified init and destroy methods via `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy`
and I'm using annotation configuration:

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
}
```

Bean:

```
@Component
//@Scope("prototype")
public class SomeBean{

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
      //Do stuff...
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void destroy() {
      //Do stuff...
  }
}
```

BeanFactoryPostProcessor:

```
@Component
public class LogAlertBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
      String[] beanDefinitionNames = beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames();

      AbstractBeanDefinition beanDefinition = null;
      for (String beanDefinitionName : beanDefinitionNames) {
          beanDefinition = (AbstractBeanDefinition) beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanDefinitionName);
      //beanDefinition.getDestroyMethodName() always NULL!!!
          if (beanDefinition.isPrototype() && beanDefinition.getDestroyMethodName() != null) { 
              System.out.println("Destroy method in \"" + beanDefinitionName + "\" bean won't be called!!!");
          }
      }
   }
}
```

In any cases methods `getDestroyMethodName` or `getInitMethodName` return null although init and destroy methods are called. Does anyone know why this happens?